# jquery using trigger('click') within the click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a custom confirm dialog when user clicks on a link with specific class. It's pretty trivial, but the catch is, if the user clicks on the "Confirm" button in the dialog (Using Twitter Bootstrap 3), I want to trigger click on the same link, but this time instead of showing dialog, to follow the link.

Everything is well up to the point when I want to trigger a click event on the `<a>` tag with some parameters. Here is very simplified sample of what I want to achieve

Html:

```
<a class="initial" href="http://yell.com">click me</a>
<div class="dialog hidden">
    <a href="#">Click me again</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.initial', function(e, forced){
    //return true;
    if(typeof(forced) !== 'undefined' && forced === true){
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        console.log('Clicked');
        return true;
    } else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $('div').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'div.dialog a', function(e){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().prev().trigger('click', [true]);
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCmar/) sample

As you can see, if the second link is clicked, the first link is colored in red, as well as console.log triggers message, but then the link doesn't follow the url. Unfortunately, I don't see any error or warning which could give me some clue. I know I can use window.location = $(element).attr('href'), but I am wondering why it is not working in the described way?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i dont quite what shall happen. you have the link "click me" and "click me again", when shall happen what when clickin which link?

Comment: I'm guessing that when you click "click me again" the default behaviour of the first link should trigger

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but why not simply put the href on the 2nd link?

Comment: what about .trigger('click', [true]);?

Comment: Last time I checked it was not possible to cause a link to navigate by triggering click event with javascript. If this was possible, spam sites could navigate to countless links each in new tab or window.

Comment: @Archer, yes good idea! I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this, for example, running

```
document.getElementById('nav-tags').click();
```

On this page will take the user to the tags page.

Therefore, it seems the issue is the jQuery trigger function.

The problem then becomes, being able to natively trigger the click event but also pass that forced boolean into the event.

The solution I came up with is to remove the second argument, and to set a state in the original link via `data`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.initial', function(e){
    //return true;
    if($(this).data('trigger') === true) {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        console.log('Clicked');
    } else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $('div').removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).data('trigger', false);
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'div.dialog a', function(e){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().prev().data('trigger', true).get(0).click();
});
```

[JSF](http://jsfiddle.net/RCmar/3/)

Comment: sorry but that is not true

Comment: The The example doesn't work (Chrome 32.0.1700.107), but it's working f you add setTimeout. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HXeKD/ I will accept your answer, although I would implement Archer's suggestion

Comment: Simple behavior, complex solution. It not seems the best way.

Comment: Aye, if you need to add hacks in like setTimeout, I would advise to rethink your solution.

Comment: the solution is to use `triggerHandler()` instead of `trigger` thats it

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use a solution like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.initial', function(e, forced){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').removeClass('hidden').find("a").attr("href",this.href);
});
```

:) like @Archer suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.initial', function(e, forced){
    e.preventDefault();    
    //return true;
    if(typeof(forced) !== 'undefined' && forced === true){
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        console.log('Clicked');
        return true;
    } else{
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $('div').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'div.dialog a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().prev().trigger('click', [true]);
});
```

Comment: check e.preventDefault() is added where it is to be!

Comment: Ah ok, didn't see it at first.

Answer (score 1):

okey. I found something. This is already a bug in jquery as per the below ticket, but closed.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11326

And the workaround is adding a span(or similar) inside the anchor and add click on that. Please find below the fiddle for same

http://jsfiddle.net/RCmar/2/

**HTML**

```
<a class="initial" href="http://yell.com"><span>click me</span></a>
<div class="dialog hidden"><a href="#">Click me again</a></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.initial span', function(e, forced){
    //return true;
    alert(1);
    if(typeof(forced) !== 'undefined' && forced === true){
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        console.log('Clicked');
        return true;
    } else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $('div').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'div.dialog a', function(e){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().prev().children().trigger('click', [true]);
});
```

Comment: I thought you want to land to that page. What exactly you want? I think I missed the big part.

Comment: Yes, I want exactly this, but using your jsfiddle sample it doesn't. (Chrome 32.0.1700.107). I will use Archer's suggestion, but it's also possible to make it your way, but adding setTimeout() as in the accepted answer.

Comment: ok. I am using Firefox actually. Any way main thing is its fixed.